# The etymology of 'substance'. Does it mean 'sub'-'stance'?

Tags: meaning, etymology, latin, greek

I am aware of the etymological fallacy and aware that the fallacy itself, also, does not always hold good. In other words, a word's pedigree may, or may not, be the reason it means what it means, today.

---

The [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/193042?redirectedFrom=substance#eid) tells me, in the small print, that, beyond the immediate Anglo Norman *substans* lies the Old French *sustance* and beyond that lies the Latin *substare*, literally *sub-stare* 'to stand' or to 'stand under'.

Interestingly, there is a concomitant word in Hellenistic Greek 'υποστασις, *hupostasis* which, literally, is as the Latin, and can be rendered 'under-upstanding'.

The Latin word *substantia* was adopted (Vulgate etc) to translate both 'υποστασις, *hupostatis* and also ουσια, *ousia*.

Now these two Greek words mean, respectively, immaterial presence and material presence. That is to say, the non-physical aspect and the physical aspect of that which is.

Thus the Latin word *substantia* - and then the English word 'substance' - came to have twin meanings, originally - it would seem - from the Greek.

---

'Substance' in the [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/193042?redirectedFrom=substance#eid) is defined as the 'nature' or the 'essence' of something.

My question is - has there been an etymological fault in the development of the word ? Is it actually wrong, conceptually, to use a word which means 'underneath that which stands' to convey both meanings of 'physical material' and 'non-physical being' ?

And has this caused confusion, historically, in the conveying of metaphysical concept ? That is to say, has the concept of 'physical material' been carried over into the understanding of that which is not 'physical material' ?

'Essence' or 'subsistence' conveys absolute being.
'Substance' conveys that which is substantive, that which is materially present.

Should they not have been kept separate ?

And is this word 'substance', therefore, an example of an etymological fallacy ?

Comment: The etymological fallacy is the belief/dogma that 'the original sense of a word **must** inform its **present-day** meaning'. It is a universal truth. It says nothing about whether semantic shifts have or have not happened in individual cases (ie it does **not** demand that the original sense of a particular word can never inform its present-day meaning). / This is fundamentally a good question (though 'Should they not have been kept separate?' is academic. We have what we have.) It involves the st. Sapir-Whorf hypothesis. I'm not sure whether it might not be more appropriate on Philosophy SE

Comment: I forget who first said 'All words are infinitely polysemous [even "formaldehyde"]'. But as in English studies, words dealing with philosophical entities (?) are variously defined by different authorities, and often understood differently. I remember that the Greeks considered the nature of man to be tripartite, while the Jews held an essentially bipartite view. This means that 'soul' say is going to be perceived differently. One needs to understand what the original users understood by a [previous] term, not just the comparison (eg 'stand under') being put forward, which others might reject.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thank you. I am intrigued about the Sapir-Whorf reference. My own thought in this particular case is that language has been manipulated by the culture prevalent in England. That is to say, the concepts of 'essence' and 'substance' have been deliberately blurred by manipulation of the language. –

Comment: Are you suggesting a deliberate attempt to manipulate beliefs / ideologies? This becomes a very difficult area to explore. While you may well be right (if you _are_ suggesting this), people understandably grab hold of existing words and possible analogies to try to explain concepts they are struggling to explain (first to themselves). For instance, with the Athenasian Creed,  I think I can handle 'without confounding the persons' (probably wrongly), but 'nor dividing the substance' demands I know what exactly is meant by 'substance' here. I don't; using 'the nature / essence' merely ...

Comment: substitutes replacement terms I can't really comprehend in this context.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth In the creed you mention, perhaps 'nature' is a better word than 'substance'. Person and nature are common to all. 'Substance' is not.

Comment: It was decided upon by a plethora of clerics. [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/substance) has _substance: ultimate reality that underlies all outward manifestations and change_. And this is listed before the 'material' sense and hence is at least as acceptable a usage.  I'm saying I don't understand a tri-unity having a non-divisible ultimate reality.

Comment: Note: _substans_ doesn’t mean ‘underneath that which stands’, but rather ‘that which stands underneath [something else]’. Similarly, _ὑπόστασις_ means ‘under-standing’ (as in ‘standing under’, that is, not as in comprehending), not ‘under-upstanding’—I’m not sure what that would even mean in English. It is also worth mentioning that _essence_ (Lat. _essentia_) is a direct calque of Greek _οὐσία_: an abstract feminine noun formed from the present participle of the verb ‘to be’, i.e., ‘a being’. The rest of your question is, I’m afraid, philosophically over my head.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Thank you for that. ὑπόστασις - stasis is that which rises up (sedition) or which, itself, stands upright. So huper -stasis is something underneath. Thayer gives 'substructure'.

Comment: Semantically, in actual Greek, probably; _στάσις_ was a very common word with many meanings. Etymologically, it’s simply an abstract verbal noun from the root underlying the verb _ἵστημι_ (_hístemi_, ‘to stand’), so it’s base meaning is simply ‘a standing’. My main objection to the translation ‘upstanding’ was that that is a more (etymologically/part-for-part) accurate translation of _ἀνάστασις_ (_anástasis_), which is specifically _ἀνα-_ ‘up’ + _στάσις_ ‘standing’.

Comment: In other words, a more obvious Greek word to gloss as ‘under-upstanding’ would be _ὑπανάστασις_. This doesn’t really seem to have existed as such, but the corresponding verb, _ὑπανίσταμαι_ (_hypanístamai_), does exist, meaning ‘rise up, be raised above the land’; and from the verb, the noun could be productively formed.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Αναστασις (ana, again, stasis, rise up) is the word for resurrection. [Thayer, again.]

Comment: Yes, that is one meaning of it; _ἀνά_ can mean both ‘up’ and ‘again’ (and many other things). It also retains (in Classical Greek) its basic meaning of ‘standing up’ or ‘rising up’, from mediopassive _ἀνίσταμαι_); and ‘make someone stand up [and leave] (= rout)’ or ‘make something stand up (= erect, set up)’, from active _ἀνίστημι_. The resurrective senses are extensions of these basic meanings.

Comment: What is the basis for the assumption, which suddenly appears in the fifth paragraph of this question, that οὐσία means (only) *material* presence?

Comment: @jsw29 Thayer 1885 4th edition p.466 _what one has, property, possessions, estate_. That is Thayer's principal, primary and only meaning.

Answer (score 2):

There doesn’t appear to have been any confusion in the historical development of the term according to the [following Etymonline information](https://www.etymonline.com/word/substance). The Greek root meant “essence or nature of anything” and Latin *substantia*  refers also to “stand firm, be present”:

> - c. 1300, "essential nature, real or essential part," from Old French sustance, substance "goods, possessions; nature, composition" (12c.), from Latin substantia "being, essence, material," ***from substans, present participle of substare "stand firm, stand or be under, be present,"*** from sub "up to, under" (see sub-) + stare "to stand," from PIE root *sta- "to stand, make or be firm."
> - Latin substantia translates Greek ousia "***that which is one's own, one's substance or property; the being, essence, or nature of anything.***" Meaning "any kind of corporeal matter" is first attested mid-14c. Sense of "the matter of a study, discourse, etc." first recorded late 14c.

(Etymonline)

***[Substance](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/substance)
:***

> Any material that possesses physical properties is called a substance. ***The word also refers to the gist or main idea of something***. If you remember the main point of a lesson, you've got the substance.

History:

> - ***The meaning of the noun substance has evolved over time, yet it has always been related to something sound and solid — from the Latin root substare, which means "to stand firm," to the Middle English definition as an "essential nature.***" Nowadays, we use the word to define someone who possesses honesty and intelligence, or when we examine a message to find its essence. To be thought of as a "person of substance" is a good thing, but to be thought of as a "substance abuser" is not so good.

(Vocabulary.com)

Comment: Yes, your reference points out that _substantia_ translates _ousia_. But the Greek word _ousia_ does not refer to the _being_ of a person. 'Substance and property' are not the same as the metaphysical being. Nor is the 'nature' of a person the same as the _being_ of a person.

Comment: +1 for the edited version, which is helpful.

Comment: @NigelJ - My view is Greek *ousia* is grammatically the same as *being* in English, and Latin lacks this form, forcing a different word such as *essence* or *substance* and so causing confusion in philosophy and theology, particularly as since the 4th century Christianity has believed God the Father and God the Son are the same *ousia*. The alternative is to follow Humpty Dumpty whose words mean what he chooses them to mean.

Comment: @Henry I disagree. The alternative (which I personally follow) is to put in the time and the effort to examine - meticulously - what the _apostles_ wrote. And, thus, to arrive at conclusions. Regards.